# List of List in for loops Java

Tags: java, list, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I have problem. I try to do develop 
Program ask me for some numbers a few times. I give list of numbers. I try to save them in  List>. Numbers can be split by space. Now I have this code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TimeSeries {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Numbers of rows:");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int NumberLines = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    String Ciag;
    List<List<Integer>> ll = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberLines; i++) {
        list.clear();
        System.out.println("Add row " +(i+1));
        Ciag = in.nextLine();
        for (int t=0; t<Ciag.length(); t++) {

            if(Character.isWhitespace(Ciag.charAt(t)))
            {

            }
            else
            {list.add(Character.getNumericValue(Ciag.charAt(t)));
            }

        }

        System.out.println(list);
        ll.add(list);
        }

    System.out.println(ll);

}


    }
```

But my output is (example) :

```
Numbers of rows:
3
Add row 1
0 0 0
[0, 0, 0]
Add row  2
1 2 3
[1, 2, 3]
Add row  3
54 6 8
[5, 4, 6, 8]
[[5, 4, 6, 8], [5, 4, 6, 8], [5, 4, 6, 8]]
```

But I need to have [[0,0, 0], [1, 2, 3], [5, 4, 6, 8]]

Comment: You are reusing the `list` reference, so you have added the same `List` multiple times. Don't reuse the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you add **the same `list`** into `ll` multiple times.
You need to add different lists to get the behavior you want.
For that, you need to create a fresh new list in each iteration of the `for` loop, instead of clearing and reusing the existing `list`.

Change these lines:

> ```
> List<List<Integer>> ll = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
> List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
> for (int i = 0; i < NumberLines; i++) {
>     list.clear();
> ```

To this:

```
List<List<Integer>> ll = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < NumberLines; i++) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```